# How to replace tabs in string having the same tabular arrange as previous?

Tags: java

I have array of strings each of those consisting integers followed by `TAB` character. How to replace those `tabs` with `spaces` so the current formatting (arranged like a table) will remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the strings into string arrays. Collect them in a list. Calculate the max. width of each  "column" (i.e. the max. width of all elements with the same index in all arrays).

Then print the arrays using the max. width.